# Eletric field on a semi circular ring, different charges on each quarter of a ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

[image]

In this image to calculate the net eletric field is used integration from 60 degrees to -60 degrees. Ok for me by now. But then I was doing this question, number 26:

[image]

And he solves by doing that:

[image]

1) Should the integration be from 90 to 180 and then from 180 to 270? 
2) Why is he using cos45?

I understand that the net force would point 45 degrees clockwise from the upper part of the ring, but shouldn't the limits be based on where are the charges?

Answer (score 0):

The field of each quarter circle is evaluated separately about its symmetry axis:

[image]

which is why the limits are taken the way the answer shows.